# Server sent event client is not working in Java project

Tags: java, android, server-sent-events

I am trying to implement SSE client in java from this [tutorial](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/sse.html#sse.ex.client.eventListener).
It is working fine when implemented as Servlet client using post method.But it is not working when I am implementing the same in Java project using main method and with same jar files as in servlet.Here is the code I am using along with target URI:-

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.EventListener;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.EventSource;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.InboundEvent;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.SseFeature;


public class SSEreceive {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
      Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(SseFeature.class).build();



      WebTarget target =   ((Client)client).target("http://www.w3schools.com/html/demo_sse.php");



      EventSource eventSource = (EventSource)EventSource.target(target).build();

      EventListener listener = new EventListener() {
        @Override
        //@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public void onEvent(InboundEvent inboundEvent) {
          //  System.out.println(inboundEvent.getName() + "; " + inboundEvent.readData(String.class));  
          System.out.println(inboundEvent.readData(String.class));
        }
      };

      //eventSource.register(listener, "message-to-client");

      eventSource.register(listener);
      eventSource.open();
      System.out.println("Connection tried");
      eventSource.close();

    } catch (ProcessingException pe) {
      pe.printStackTrace();
      System.out.println(pe.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Can some please help me why this is not working in Java project ?

Comment: I am trying to implement the same code in Android application for SSE and the target URL-http://www.w3schools.com/html/demo_sse.php .But it is not working in android.Please tell me if I have missed any thing in ANDROID MANIFEST FILE.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide the logs, or which steps are working.

Comment: Remember the response should have the `'Content-Type: text/event-stream'` header and `charset="utf-8"`